# Mongoose query an array contain one of value in another array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

How do I check if an element of an array belongs to another array in Mongoose? For example, I have a document:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
favor:Array
})

user1 = {
name:'John',
favor : ['banana', 'apple', 'eggs'].
}

user 2= {
name:'Ethan',
favor : ['apple', 'eggs'].
}
```

and I have an Array

```
const array = ['eggs', 'banana']
```

I want to get user1. How can I do with mongoose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `$all` operator for this scenario

```
db.collection.find({
  favor: {
    $all: [
      "eggs",
      "banana"
    ]
  }
})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/